# MSTest: Why does HttpContext.Current become null after a test method finishes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, mstest

I'm writing a series of unit tests for an ASP.NET project using MSTest. Some of the code being tested assumes that `HttpContext.Current` is not null, so I'm working on setting up a dummy `HttpContext.Current` to avoid `NullReferenceException` getting thrown when the tests run.

Since in my situation, the actual content of `HttpContext.Current` is unimportant -- it just needs to be non-null -- my initial approach was to set up a dummy `HttpContext.Current` just once in my test class's `AssemblyInitialize` method, and let all test methods use that.

This worked fine for a single test method.  However, after each test method completes, I observed that `HttpContext.Current` would become null, and the second and subsequent tests would consequently fail.

Here's a simplified complete test class that illustrates this behavior:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void RunOnceBeforeTestsBegin(TestContext context)
    {
        // Set up a dummy HttpContext.Current for testing
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest("", "http://example.com/", "");
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
        HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(request, response);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(HttpContext.Current);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(HttpContext.Current);
    }
}
```

In my Visual Studio 2013, when I run the tests in this class:

- TestMethod2 runs first and passes;
- TestMethod1 runs second, and fails because `HttpContext.Current` is null.

(I realize I can work around this problem by setting up my fake `HttpContext.Current` once for each individual test method, e.g. in a `TestInitialize` method.)

My question: **Why does `HttpContext.Current` become null after each test method runs?**